# confused by insert on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to implement a 3 table item tagging system

Table: Item
Columns: ItemID (primary, auto_increment), Title, Content

Table: Tag
Columns: TagID (primary, auto_increment), Title, TagCount

Table: ItemTag
Columns: ItemID, TagID

Each Title of a tag is unique.
I would like to implement an efficient way of inserting to the Tag table:
1. Check if Title exists
2. If it exists, update TagCount+1
3. Else if it doesn't exist, insert

I looked into INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but I'm confused if it can be applied because my key is the TagID and not the Title.

Comment: Question1: does Item.Title and Tag.Title hold different values?
Question2: Shouldn't the TagCount be on the ItemTag table with a primary key on (ItemID, TagID)?

Comment: Q1: different values Q2: TagCount is the number of ItemTags for that given Tag.  I want to store it just for efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to do the insert into the table "Tag".

You need to modify the table and add a unique index on the title field :

```
alter table tag add unique index title(title);
```

Then, you can do the following

```
insert into tag (Title, TagCount) values ('blah',1)
on duplicate key update TagCount = TagCount + 1;
```

Hopefully that does the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is to make the 'Title' field in Tag Unique.

If you do that, then you could do:

```
INSERT INTO Tag (Title, TagCount) VALUES ('<value>', 1)
```

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TagCount = TagCount + 1;